# Hook process socket calls from kernel driver

Tags: windows, sockets, hook, windows-kernel

Can anybody give me an example of kernel driver which can hook process socket calls (send, receive and etc.) and itercept it with my own functions?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linux module to hook process functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373447/linux-module-to-hook-process-functions)

Comment: sorry, you gave me a link to linux hook, i asked windows

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in kernel by using TDI filter. Check this out: http://www.codemachine.com/article_tdi.html

But TDI filter works on protocol level of network framework. So it is based on TCP/UDP protocol etc.

If you want to implement this lower. You can try to use NDIS filter. Check this out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff565492(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Is not recommendable using TDI filters in Vista and later OS. Its considered deprecated in that and later OS and using it would creates a lot of network performance problems. Better using Windows Filtering Platform (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg463267.aspx) if is that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Winsock Layer Service Providers](http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0599/layeredservice/layeredservice.aspx) might be of help to you. It allows you to intercept Winsock calls, but in user-mode. This makes development much smoother and the application more stable.